# Finding delta for epsilon-delta definition of a piece wise function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

I am trying to find the necessary $\delta$ that satisfies the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity of the following function at $x = 0$:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ for } x \ge 0,\\ 
x^2 & \text{ for } x < 0.\end{cases}$$

My work:

right limit:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0+}x$ $\implies \forall \epsilon$ $\exists \delta $  ($|x|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)|< \epsilon)$

clearly we can let $\delta = \epsilon$ as $f(x) = x$

For the left limit:

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0-}x^2$ $\implies \forall \epsilon$ $\exists \delta $  ($|x|<\delta$ $\implies$ $|f(x)|< \epsilon)$

here we let $\delta = \sqrt\epsilon$ as $f(x) = x^2$

My problem is that which $\delta$ do I choose?

Comment: Take $\delta=\min\{\epsilon,\sqrt\epsilon\}$.

Comment: In fact, if $0<\varepsilon<1$, $\delta=\min\{\varepsilon,\sqrt\varepsilon\}=\varepsilon$

Comment: @TitoEliatron so which one do I choose? Do I choose the $\delta$ which is a minimum when it is close to the limit?

Comment: In an $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, only small values fo $\varepsilon$ matters, son you ALWAYS can assume that $\varepsilon<1$. So,  you can take $\delta=\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found one value $\delta_1 > 0$ and used it to prove a statement of the form

- $|x| < \delta_1 \implies P(x)$

then you can replace $\delta_1$ by any value $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta \le \delta_1$ and it will *still be true* that

- $|x| < \delta \implies P(x)$

Using that, suppose you have two values $\delta_1 > 0$ and $\delta_2 > 0$, and you have proved two statements like this:

- $|x| < \delta_1 \implies P(x)$
- $|x| < \delta_2 \implies Q(x)$

It follows that you can replace each of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ by the same value $\delta = \min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, and then you'll know its true that

- $|x| < \delta \implies P(x) \quad\text{and}\quad Q(x)$

In your problem, you have $\delta_1 = \epsilon$ and $\delta_2 = \sqrt{\epsilon}$, and so you use $\delta = \min\{\epsilon,\sqrt{\epsilon}\}$.